# Saving vocabulary object from pytorch's torchtext library

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

Building a text classification model using pytorch's torchtext . The vocabulary object is in the data.field :

```
def create_tabularDataset_object(self,csv_path):
   self.TEXT = data.Field(tokenize=self.tokenizer,batch_first=True,include_lengths=True)
   self.LABEL = data.LabelField(dtype = torch.float,batch_first=True)
```

```
def get_vocab_with_glov(self,data):
   # initialize glove embeddings
   self.TEXT.build_vocab(data,min_freq=100,vectors = "glove.6B.100d")
```

After training , when serving the model in production how do i hold the TEXT object ? at prediction time  i need it for indexing the words tokens

```
[TEXT.vocab.stoi[t] for t in tokenizedׁ_sentence]
```

am i missing something and it is not necessary to hold  that object ? Do i need any other file other then the model weights ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that i can save it as a pkl:
Saving the TEXT.vocab as a pkl worked :

```
def save_vocab(vocab, path):
    import pickle
    output = open(path, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(vocab, output)
    output.close()
```

Where

```
vocab = TEXT.vocab
```

and reading it as usual.

Comment: Thank you very for your answer! I wonder do you know how to use `torchtext` for inference? I assume we can `load` all Fields, them it seems it should use `torchtext.data.Example` to load one single example, this is where I stuck.

Comment: @com if you have the trained model file and the vocab you can use something similar to here: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/01/first-text-classification-in-pytorch/

Comment: Yes, it seems like I can use this, Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Actually the best way (more stable) to do this is to use torch built-in function torch.save(*)

Example to save file:

```
torch.save(vocab_obj, 'vocab_obj.pth')
```

To load the file again:

```
vocab_obj = torch.load('vocab_obj.pth')
```